# Noise on Bluetooth Low Energy module power supply

Tags: wireless, switch-mode-power-supply, noise

I have a bluetooth low energy module (BLE112), which I'm trying to use on my PCB. When I supply JUST the module with a coin cell battery, it works great and I can see it advertising on my wireless packet sniffer. But when I switch to powering it with the 3.3V rail on my PCB, it won't do any wireless communication anymore, though I can still communicate with it over the USART. I am pretty confident that the problem is related to noise on the supply line, as it will still fail when the only wires going to the module are 3.3V and ground. The documentation for the module says that the RF ground is connected internally to the regular ground; is that part of the problem? The documentation also says a ferrite bead is recommended to be used to filter out excessive noise in the power supply lines, but how do I choose one and where does it go?

What can I do to get rid of the noise?

Comment: Do you also have a decoupling capacitor near the BLE112?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the design spec of the module. Use a ferrite bead as well as put a cap in parallel with your supply. There should be a few caps on your PCB to prevent noise.

Source: designed hardware around 112.

Comment: How do I know what ferrite bead to use? I don't see it in the datasheet.

Comment: you have to use one that is rated for your supply voltage. If your passing ~3 volts directly to your module then you need to use one rated for ~3v.